# Fitness app that allows recording food consumed by weight and not by volumetric serving?

Tags: nutrition, nutrition-information, app

myfitnesspal.com has a large database of foods with their nutritional value stored, and allows one to add in how much one has consumed by the volumetric servings, e.g. 1 cup of carrots.

However, it doesn't make sense for me to measure out the foods I consume by volume.  This is because it's very easy to carry around a small food scale, but not a series of measuring cups.  I keep my own records by the total weight of the food, e.g. 200 grams of mango, rather than 1 cup of mango.

Is there a (free) app or website which has the same comprehensive database but allows recording the weight of the food consumed, rather than the 'serving'?

Comment: The USDA database (which is the starting point for almost any nutrition database) both weight and volumetric.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When searching for a food, add the keyword "gram".

Example: grams carrot, grams apple, ect

Typically the serving size is 100 grams, but you can change it to 1 gram.

[image] [image]